# Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0

Tags: ffmpeg

I use this command on ffmpeg :

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -ss 40 -t 40 -i mymusic.mp3 -ab 15 voice.mp3 2>&1
```

but I see this error :

```
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format mp3 (codec png) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually. Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0
```

Also lamemp3 installed and enabled, how can I fix it?

this is complete output :

```
ffmpeg version N-81842-g0fbd423 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
  configuration: --enable-decoder=png --enable-encoder=png
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 60.101 / 57. 60.101
  libavformat    57. 51.102 / 57. 51.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 63.100 /  6. 63.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
[mp3 @ 0x3ccd3c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'mymusic.mp3':
  Metadata:
    album_artist    : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    title           : Eshtebah .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    artist          : Abolfazl Fallah .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    album           : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    comment         : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    genre           : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    track           : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    copyright       : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    TOPE            : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    composer        : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    TBPM            : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    TIT3            : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    encoded_by      : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    disc            : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    MusicMatch_Mood : .:.:. WWW.NEWSONG3.COM .:.:.
    date            : 2013
  Duration: 00:04:08.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 129 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 300x300 [SAR 96:96 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format mp3 (codec png) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0
```

Comment: We can't suggest anything without seeing the **complete** console output from the command.

Comment: this problem just for are files that contain photos!

Comment: if remove photo from tags, fix it

Comment: but we want to use cover (photo) for musics! now, how can i fix it error??

Comment: As I mentioned before I need to see the output to know what is actually happening. I prefer not give guesses as answers. However, I can tell you that `-ab` value is in bits, so 15 bits/second is unusable. I suspect you wanted `-ab 15k` (which is still very low for libmp3lame).

Comment: Your `ffmpeg` was not compiled with support for any MP3 encoder. For solutions see duplicate question link at top of page.

Comment: i was 3 Times compiled ffmpeg complete! but, this problem was not fix!! your answer cant help me! sorry

Comment: I show multiple solutions to the problem. Which did you try?